# How do I apply a css padding to one element but not its child

Tags: css, padding

Given the following code

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <p><img src="image.jpg"><p>
  <p>More Text</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 640px;
}

.container p {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

When there's an image, i don't want it to inherit the padding from the p. How can I do this? Keep in mind, I cannot change the actual html, just the css.

Comment: Why can't you change the html?

Comment: I think something else is going on. An `img` tag will not inherit padding from a `p` under most circumstances.

Comment: Why would the image inherit the padding of its parent? Did you set images to inherit padding somewhere? Or do you want the paragraph to not have padding if it contains an image?

Comment: I can't change the html because TinyMCE is adding the <p>'s around the images and I don't want to parse all the articles to remove those <p>s.

Comment: @Jeff I'm not sure what you mean, the img tag is nested inside the <p>. It's picking up the padding from .container p. I'm trying to make it not do that.

Comment: animuson: That's exactly what i want to do. No padding if the paragraph contains an image.

Comment: @tkaravou That's not possible using pure CSS. CSS selectors only go from parents down to children. You cant go up from a child to a parent. You can use JavaScript to determine if the paragraphs have an image and add padding then. Or parse the TinyMCE markup like you said you didnt want to do. Or just live with the padding on the image.

Comment: @tkaravou You could try negative margins on the image, but that could be problematic too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what you mean. Padding isn't inheritted...

Do you mean you don't want the p that contains an img tag to have the padding?

You could try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <p><div class="center"><img src="afb.png"></div><p>
  <p>More Text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 640px;
}

.container p {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.container p img {
  margin: -10px -20px;
}

.center{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. There's only on thing though. I want the image to be centered so i was using margin: -10px auto.. obviously I can't do that anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: I cant see a possibility to change that without changing the html (unless by using javascript to change your html, but i don't like that option at all). If you could find a way to change your html, you could change it like you see in my last edit...

Comment: @animuson: Oh, yes, you're right, I've editted it, now it should be ok again. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another css rule that overrides the second one

```
.container p img
{
   padding : 0 0;
}
```

Comment: That was my first guess. It doesn't work though because it's inside the p so it's too late. Negative padding also doesn't work..